# Corosync/Pacemaker pcs equivalent commands to crm

Tags: crm, pacemaker, corosync

I know `crm` utility command has been people's preferred method to manage clusters when it comes to High Availability with corosync & pacemaker. Now, its been deprecated and we are told to work with `pcs` utility commands which suppose to do all sort of things that we used to do with `crm`.

Now what I am troubling with is to find the `pcs` equivalent command to;

`crm node attribute <node_name> set <resource_name> <some_parameters>`

I am at CentOS 7.2 version & working with Percona master-slave cluster.

Comment: How about this: http://clusterlabs.org/man/pacemaker/crm_attribute.8.html ?

Answer (score 0):

This actually can be done with pcs version 0.9.158.

The reason I had trouble of finding the pcs equivalent to crm was I was using older version which is pcs-0.9.143